# All rows returned in phpMyAdmin but only 1 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I run this query in phpMyAdmin it loads all the rows.
But when I run it through PHP SQL, I only get the first row.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and I'm really getting stressed out.

Here's my code:

```
    function getRows($user)
{
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT day(closed) AS day, COUNT( closed ) AS c FROM ost_ticket WHERE year(closed) = '2013' AND monthname(closed) = 'January' AND source = '{$user}'  GROUP BY day LIMIT 30");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($q);
    return $count;
}
function test11($user)
{
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ost_ticket WHERE closed LIKE  '%2013-06-   19%' AND source = '" . $user. "'");
       if(!$q)
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
 $r = 0;
$a = mysql_num_rows($q);
echo $a;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{   
return $row['status'];
return $row['day'];
$r++;
}
}
 function getUser()
 {
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ost_staff WHERE staff_id > 2");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    {
            $count1 = getRows($row['username']);
            $a = 0;
        echo '<div id="' . $row['username'] . '" class="stat">
        <span class="title">' . $row['username'] . '</span><br /><br />
        <div id="break"></div>';
        echo '
        <div id="data-' . $row['username'] .'">' . test11($row['username'])   . '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    }
}

Thanks in advance for this.
```

Comment: _Which_ query? You have three.

Comment: Ahh, the second one I bet, `test11()`.  Because you are returning from the function on the first loop iteration.

Comment: You are using return inside while that's the reason you are getting only row.

Answer (score 2):

A function exits on the first reached RETURN statement.

So, your function just returns one `$row['status'];`. You should put query results in an array and return it.

Answer (score 1):

You use `return` in `while` loop - your code exits the function when it encounters first `return`. This is probably the reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{   
    return $row['status']; //Returns in only this value
    return $row['day'];
    $r++;
}
```

Fix:

```
$a = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{   
    $a['status'][] =  $row['status'];
    $a['day'][] = $row['day'];
    //$r++;
}
return $a; //This will return an array with all the rows fetched.
```

Comment: Is $a multidimensional array ?

Comment: Hmm, The two lines inside while seems weird. I mean in PHP the functioning of the array is totally different from conventional languages like C,C++ etc.

Comment: @Vivek, Yeah... they look rare. Actually, what it does is to push a value into the array. At the end it will look like this: `array('status' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 3), 'day' => array(0 => 'monday', 1 => 'wendsday'))`